# query a newly created table using $wpdb

Tags: wpdb

i created a new table inside my wordpress database called `forms`, this table consist of `ID` and `names`

i want to query all the list from this table using the wordpress `$wpdb`

this is my code below

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM  $wpdb->forms" );
    foreach ( $result as $print ) {
          echo $print->ID.'<br/>';
   }
?>
```

but im only getting a text `Array` from my `echo`

Answer (score 1):

you doing something wrong your `$result` query returns multidimensional array of rows and each row has an array of keys values, try this, not tested but will work.

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM  $wpdb->forms" );
foreach ( $result as $key => $row ) {
      echo $row->ID.'<br/>';
}
?>
```